# Using Magick in R to circle crop a png and add a circle border with specific thickness and colour

Tags: r, imagemagick

I have been able to use the following code to take an image and apply a circle crop to the original photo.

However what I want to end up with is the players face as cropped in the image, but to maintain a border in the shape of the circle crop (and to specify the color and thickness of this border) to result with an image that is a full circle shape with the face inside the circle?

I have been totally unable to find out how to apply a circle border to the circle crop and specify the color and thickness of this border?

```
# Load libraries
library(magick)
library(image.libfacedetection)

# Resize fit function
resize_fit <- function(image, size = 600) {
  info <- image_info(image)
  size <- min(size, info$width, info$height)
  image_resize(
    image,
    geometry_size_pixels(
      height = if (info$width >= info$height) size,
      width = if (info$height > info$width) size
    )
  )
}

# find face center function
find_face_center <- function(image) {
  detections <- image.libfacedetection::image_detect_faces(image)$detections
  best_face <- which(detections$confidence == max(detections$confidence))
  dims <- as.list(detections[best_face[[1]], ])
  list(
    x = dims$x + dims$width / 2,
    y = dims$y + dims$height / 2
  )
}

# Crop offset function
crop_offset <- function(point, range, width) {
  # 4. Catch the edge case first
  if (width >= range) return(0)
  
  if ((point - width / 2) < 0) {
    # 1. must start at left edge
    return(0)
  }
  if ((point + width / 2) > range) {
    # 2. must start at right edge
    return(range - width)
  }
  # 3. enough space on both sides to center width in range
  point - width / 2
}

# Function

resize_crop_to_face <- function(image, size = 600) {
  image <- resize_fit(image, size)
  info <- image_info(image)
  
  # size may have changed after refit
  size <- min(info$height, info$width)
  
  is_image_square <- info$width == info$height
  if (is_image_square) {
    return(image)
  }
  
  face <- find_face_center(image)
  
  image_crop(
    image,
    geometry = geometry_area(
      width = size,
      height = size,
      x_off = crop_offset(face$x, info$width, size),
      y_off = crop_offset(face$y, info$height, size)
    )
  )
}


# Import an image
my_image <- image_read("https://static.www.nfl.com/image/private/t_player_profile_landscape_2x/f_auto/league/aspau9t4rjwirkedoz5o")

# Apply function
my_image <- resize_crop_to_face(my_image)



# Calculate dimensions
image_info <- image_info(my_image)
image_min_dimensions <- min(image_info$height,
                            image_info$width)


# Draw circle


fig <- image_draw(image_blank(image_min_dimensions,image_min_dimensions))

symbols(image_min_dimensions/2,
        image_min_dimensions/2,
        circles = (image_min_dimensions/2)-3,
        bg = "white",
        inches = FALSE,
        add = TRUE)

my_image_2 <- image_composite(fig,
                              my_image,
                              operator = "in")

my_image_2
```

Comment: We can't see what you expect to end up with...

Comment: Hi. The code in the snippet produces a circle cropped image but I need to find out how I can put a circle border of specified thickness and color around my_image_2 if that makes sense?